# Querying multiple values on comma separated field

Tags: mysql

As an example I have this as a field in a column:

> 3,21,23,41,47,56,57,61,64,74,78,79,82,83,86,90,94

These are IDs and I'm trying to figure out how I can search for multiple numbers I've tried for example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status='A' AND (FIND_IN_SET('3,64', myids))
```

This only seems to work if the 3 and 64 were together and outputting the find_in_set for each value could be a bit of a pain.

Any better solutions or suggestions?

Comment: You should seriously consider adapting your table structure - querying this kind of data in a RDBMS is a PITA. Better use a detail table instead - much cleaner, easier to query/delete/update/insert single records etc.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm working with a database that already exists (else I would have done it differently :(  ).

Comment: In this case, I'd go for regular expressions - you cannot use simple substring search, since searching for '3' will also find '23' etc. Something like ... WHERE myids rlike('(^|,)3(,|$)') and myids rlike('(^|,)64(,|$)'), which matches the beginning of the string or a , followed by your number followed by the end of the string or a comma (not 100% sure about MySQL regex syntax, though).

Comment: For those closing this question because *"This question appears to be off-topic because it's just awful"* ... would you mind stating why this is all that awful, and wouldn't a default (non-snarky) close reason suffice?

Answer (score 2):

`FIND_IN_SET()` only finds the position of the first argument (see [MySQL Reference, String Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)).

You may use a single `FIND_IN_SET` for each id you are looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status='A' AND
  FIND_IN_SET('3', myids) AND FIND_IN_SET('64', myids)
```

Comment: But this will also match '63' and '264', won't it?

Comment: No, it won't! A set is a list of strings separated by comma and `FIND_IN_SET` only returns the index, where the _complete_ string is found.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE myids REGEXP REPLACE("3,64", ',', '(\\,|$)|');
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Exact Answer For this Issue... I tried so many methods... This is the best i ever seen.

Comment: This is the Perfect Solution but can someone explain what's going on here :)

Comment: This solution is not going to work. It will pick records even if they have 303,403, 43 etc because it matches the string is existed @jamessekar007

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status='A' AND myids in (3, 64)
```

You can try this one.

Answer (score 0):

So if we have to look for both sides with **exact comma** separations we have to do this.

```
# Example:
# A: myids = 1,2,20,3,30
# B: myfind = 2,3
# This WHERE Print: 2 and 3


SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONCAT(',', myids, ',') REGEXP CONCAT(',(', REPLACE('2,3', ',', '|'), ',)');
```

LIST OF INVALID FUNCTIONS **NOT TO BE USED**:

> - SELECT * FROM table WHERE status='A' AND myids in (3, 64)
> - SELECT * FROM table WHERE myids REGEXP REPLACE("3,64", ',', '(\,|$)|');

One of the **reasons** not to use is that it looks for the **same 3 as 30** or 300 same for 2 or 20 200 etc

Answer (score -2):

```
foreach($ids as $id)
{
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE status='A' AND (FIND_IN_SET($id, myids))
}

that check one by one and getting the result from table.
```